# Unable to deploy to Elastic Beanstalk via Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat6, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have Eclipse running with the AWS plugin.
And I have made a new a simple web application and can run it locally successfully.
But when I try to run it on the AWS Elastic Beanstalk for Tomcat6, I get a message saying:

> Unable to connect to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. Make sure you've
>   registered your account for the AWS Elastic Beanstalk Service.

I have registered my account for AWS Elastic Beanstalk Service and I think I filled the right Access Key ID and Secret Access Key.

Answer (score 1):

1. Confirm that you have Elastic Beanstalk under "Services You're Signed Up For" on AWS Portal: https://portal.aws.amazon.com/gp/aws/manageYourAccount
2. Make sure that all required fields on AWS Toolkit preferences pane are filled out:

[image: Example preferences]